# Another "No such file or directory" error in qt5

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5

So, I encounter another interesting "no such file or directory" error in my program.

The interesting thing is, when I typed the classes I include in my source code, which are **QGraphicsItem** and **QGraphicsView** in this case, no warning was given. But when I tried to built it in Qt creator, it raise an error and told me that **"C1083: can not open include file:No such file or directory"**.  (The header file both locate at  **D:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets**)

Also, I went check the include path in my qt5.4 file, which is **D:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include** in his case, I did exactly find the two header files.

Has any one met this error before? Can explain it?

And by the way, which is the default include path in qt creator and how to change it?

Comment: You might want to add more than one include paths where the compiler with search for include files. Consider `D:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore` or/and `D:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui` etc.

Comment: @vahancho Change it . doesn't work still.

Comment: What are the missing include files and where they are located?

Comment: @vahancho oh sorry I forget to post that. I will edit the question

Comment: Does adding `D:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets` as an include path make any difference?

Comment: @vahancho no. so weird...

Answer (score 3):

You should check your `.pro` file for this line:

```
QT += core gui widgets
```

I would recommend to add `widgets` to your `QT` variable.

Yhis should solve your problem with path to all headers, which are realted to `QtWidgets`.

Don't forget to rebuild your project after editing `.pro` file.

In case you are building it from console you should:

1. `cd` to your project dir
2. Run `qmake`
3. Than run `make`

In case you are using QtCreator you should use `Rebuild` option